# Running a Panel Regression in R - What is the "Between" model?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I'm running regressions on an unbalanced panel dataset. I've ran panel regressions in other software, but this is my first time in R.

I have a question about the "between" model in the PLM regression library. Just to walk you through my process so far:

I've used plmtest() to determine there are significant effects within my data. From there I run a random and fixed effects regression and use phtest() to determine that one model is inconsistent and I should utilize the "within" model.

However, I have no idea how to properly test the "between" model. I've read the PLM documentation that states you can run a phtest() on the between model if you're using the chisq method, but doesn't really give any clues on interpreting the outcome. It just always says one of the models is inconsistent. I have no idea how the null and alternative hypothesis are worked out with the between.

The between model fits my data much, much better than the fixed effects model. So I would obviously prefer to use it if it is, in fact, not biased.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me a quick rundown on the between model?

Any other insight into panel regressions in R is also welcomed!

Thanks!

Comment: The between model is not specific to R or the plm package. Coverage in text books is varying in length but you should be able to find some bits about the model itself in any major econometrics / panel text book. However, I don't remember if I have seen explicit mentions of tests vs. other models, I would look into Baltagi first.